Android studio KMM Unresolved reference compile issue
I am facing an issue during the compilation of my Kotlin MP project.
:androidApp:compileDebugKotlin
Android Studio can't find some imports even if they exists and I see some "Unresolved reference" issues. I am sharing build.gradle files for project, app and shared modules.
The issue is not happening all the time. it happens sometimes.
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication).apply(false)
    alias(libs.plugins.androidLibrary).apply(false)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinAndroid).apply(false)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinMultiplatform).apply(false)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinCocoapods).apply(false)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinPluginSerialization).apply(false)
    alias(libs.plugins.sqldelight).apply(false)
    id("com.google.gms.google-services") version "4.4.0" apply false
    id("com.google.firebase.crashlytics") version "2.9.9" apply false
}

plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinAndroid)
    id("com.google.gms.google-services")
    id("com.google.firebase.crashlytics")
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinPluginSerialization)
}

android {
    namespace = "..."
    compileSdk = libs.versions.targetSdk.get().toInt()
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "..."
        minSdk = libs.versions.minSdk.get().toInt()
        targetSdk = libs.versions.targetSdk.get().toInt()
        versionCode = 12
        versionName = "1.0"

        signingConfigs {
            create("release") {
                storeFile = ...
                storePassword = "..."
                keyAlias = "..."
                keyPassword = "..."
            }
        }
    }
    buildFeatures {
        buildConfig = true
        viewBinding = true
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = libs.versions.compose.compiler.get()
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        getByName("debug") {
            applicationIdSuffix = ".debug"
            versionNameSuffix = ".debug"
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            isDebuggable = true
            isShrinkResources = false
        }
        getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = true
            isDebuggable = false
            isShrinkResources = false
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.getByName("release")
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(projects.shared)
    implementation(libs.compose.ui)
    implementation(libs.compose.ui.tooling.preview)
    implementation(libs.compose.material3)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
    implementation(libs.kotlinx.serialization.json)
    debugImplementation(libs.compose.ui.tooling)

    // jetpack nav
    implementation(libs.androidx.navigation.fragment.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.navigation.ui.ktx)

    // firebase
    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.8.0"))
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics")

    // google services
    implementation(libs.play.services.auth)

    implementation(libs.androidx.core.splashscreen)

    // material
    implementation(libs.material)
    implementation(libs.androidx.material.icons.extended)

    // koin
    implementation(libs.koin.androidx.compose)
    implementation(libs.koin.android)

    // kotlin tools
    implementation(libs.kotlinx.serialization.json)

    // coil
    implementation(libs.coil.compose)

    // constraint
    implementation(libs.androidx.constraintlayout.compose)

    // google ads
    implementation(libs.play.services.ads)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.viewbinding)

    // play review
    implementation(libs.google.play.review)
    implementation(libs.google.play.review.ktx)
}

plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinMultiplatform)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinCocoapods)
    alias(libs.plugins.androidLibrary)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinPluginSerialization)
    alias(libs.plugins.sqldelight)
}

kotlin {
    androidTarget {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions {
                jvmTarget = "17"
            }
        }
    }
//    iosX64()
//    iosArm64()
    iosSimulatorArm64()

    cocoapods {
        summary = "Some description for the Shared Module"
        homepage = "Link to the Shared Module homepage"
        version = "1.0"
        ios.deploymentTarget = "16.0"
        podfile = project.file("../iosApp/Podfile")
        framework {
            baseName = "shared"
            isStatic = true
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        commonMain.dependencies {
            implementation(libs.kotlinx.coroutines.core)
            implementation(libs.kotlinx.serialization.json)
            implementation(libs.kotlinx.datetime)
            implementation(libs.koin.core)
            api(libs.napier)
            implementation(libs.bundles.firebase)

            implementation(libs.ktor.client.core)
            implementation(libs.ktor.client.logging)
            implementation(libs.ktor.client.serialization)
            implementation(libs.ktor.client.content.negotiation)
//            implementation("org.jetbrains.androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.8.0-alpha01")
        }
        androidMain.dependencies {
            implementation(libs.ktor.client.okhttp)
            implementation(libs.sqldelight.android.driver)
            implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.5.1")
            api("com.onesignal:OneSignal:[5.0.0, 5.99.99]")
        }
        iosMain.dependencies {
            implementation(libs.ktor.client.darwin)
            implementation(libs.sqldelight.native.driver)
        }
        commonTest.dependencies {
            implementation(libs.kotlin.test)
        }
    }
}

android {
    namespace = "com.jobsapps.theoracle"
    compileSdk = libs.versions.targetSdk.get().toInt()
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = libs.versions.minSdk.get().toInt()
    }
    buildFeatures {
        buildConfig = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            isShrinkResources = false
        }
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = true
            isShrinkResources = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
}

sqldelight {
    databases {
        create("Database") {
            packageName.set("...")
        }
    }
}

What I have tried so far:

Clean project, clear gradle and .idea files


Please provide the log so we can see which dependencies were not found. That's what is displayed on the "Build" view of Android Studio in the right pane when you select the first entry in the left pane.

@Leviathan hello, thanks for your reply. All of the unresolved refs is variables, not functions or classes

Add this into your settings.gradle file.
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode = RepositoriesMode.PREFER_SETTINGS
}

This will centralise all repository urls in the settings layer instead of being managed by each module independently.
It's a recommendation since Gradle 7.

Unfortunately, it is not working. @Dan
